# Windows 8 XAML - Issue with GridView using VariableSizeWrapGrid

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have the following code on my page.

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyPage.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="400*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Some Header" FontSize="48" Margin="100, 50, 0, 0" />
            <local:CustomGridView Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100, 0, 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfYears}">
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Height="200" Width="200">
                            <Grid.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}" />
                            </Grid.Background>
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                <StackPanel.Background>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.5" />
                                </StackPanel.Background>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="24" Margin="10" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Year}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </local:CustomGridView>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

Now, I get the following image as my page.

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=59DBB22BE5D0430E!279

How do make the gridview fill up the remaining space i.e space left out after the textblock is filled? And then how do I get the variablesizewrapgrid to flow right instead of flowing down while still filling the second tile below the first and so on?

EDIT: I am looking to achieve a Windows store finish on the group. One large item and the rest just wrap around it.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Figured out the issue.

Step 1: Remove the scroll viewer.

Step 2: Set the height of the first row in the grid to some fixed value.

Step 3: Set the height of the second row in the grid to *.

Step 4: Get rid of the margin on the text block.

Step 5: Use padding instead of margin on the grid view.

This will help resolve some of it.